# How do you keep track of your financial assets while traveling / living overseas?

Tags: visas, money

Im living over seas and basically keep a spreadsheet of various assets, stocks, savings, and investments in both countries.

Does anyone have any best practice advice for managing things. Just looking for something a little easier to manage with all the currencies and stuff.

Comment: Hello, this will be a great question to ask on the new [Expatriates](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) site. I believe the mods might close this because this is an expat related question

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Actually this would be a question better suited to money.SE rather then the Expats site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about personal finance.

Comment: Yea I just noticed after I posted sorry. Feel free to nuke. Just asked on money. Might take a look at expats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of the Internet is such that your location is basically irrelevant when it comes to looking at things.  Actually taking action is a little bit harder - but not impossibly so.  As such, I would suggest:

- Use Mint for overall asset tracking.
- Use an online bank in your home country, and remain subject to them.  If you are from the United States, for example, keeping your home bank account is the simplest - and use ATMs to withdraw cash only when needed.
- Use a credit card that minimizes foreign transaction fees and has good exchange rates.

The general idea is that you don't want to convert currencies unless needed.  If you want to see your USD balance in Rupees or Rubles, by all means, but consider your stashes in two separate piles.  If you have local currency assets, think of them in the local currency.  If you want to convert back to the home currency, choose a good time to do it, and leave it there.  But the two currencies really are separate buckets, and shouldn't be confused unless you really need to.

Comment: Good points I'll take a look at mint. This is prob going to get closed because I said a bad word so I've given you the accept rep while I can. Cheers.